# Accessing the git shell in GitX on OS X

Tags: git, github, gitx

I know this sounds very basic, but I couldn't find where I can access the git shell in GitX.

A bonus question: Do I have to use the shell in order to clone a repo from GitHub?

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is no "git shell" provided by GitX. It (the shell) is rather part of the Git installation (which included also GitK, similar to GitX)

The [GitX User Manual](http://gitx.frim.nl/user_manual.html) mentions a "Enable Terminal Usage…" from GitX's menu, but that is only to launch GitX with the appropriate options in order to visualize a branch or another for instance.

---

Note: any shell (Mac or Windows) with '`git`' in the $PATH can be called a "git shell", in which you can execute "`git`" commands (`git clone`, `git push`, `git show`, ...)

But there is also, part of the Git distribution, a ["`git-shell`" command](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-shell.html), a non-interactive shell used as a login shell for SSH accounts you want to restrict to GIT pull/push access only. It permits execution only of server-side GIT commands implementing the pull/push functionality.

Both are not part of GitX.

---

Regarding cloning, as [mentioned here](http://kylecordes.com/2008/04/30/git-windows-go/), you can clone with Git Gui:

[image]

even though the command line in a shell remains the straightforward option:

```
git clone repoURL
```

Answer (score 1):

In the menubar (GitX) you can enable gitx terminal usage.

See the user [manual](http://gitx.frim.nl/user_manual.html) on Advance GitX usage.